# CAEN Reader R1270C Quarkup Communication Error

Tags: java, android, rfid

I am trying to achieve communication with Android Application to CAEN RFID reader, referencing to all the manuals, I am able to set the connection, but after connection is made I am unable to make communication with the reader. All of the commands like getting reader info, getEventMode, call to InventoryTag gives same communication error

```
public void makeConnection(UsbDevice device){
    myReader = new CAENRFIDReader();
    
    try {
        myReader.Connect((VCPSerialPort) (VCPSerialPort.findVCPDevice(this)).get(0));
        startReading();
    } catch (CAENRFIDException e) {
        if(e.getMessage().equals("Already Connected")){
            startReading();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
}

public void startReading(){
    try {
        mySource = myReader.GetSource("Source_0");
        
        mySource.SetQ_EPC_C1G2(3);
        CAENRFIDTag[] MyTags = mySource.InventoryTag();
        if (MyTags.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < MyTags.length; i++) {
                String s = new String(MyTags[i].GetId(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
                Toast.makeText(this,"ID: " + s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        //Toast.makeText(this,my[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdLe1.png)Reader.GetEventMode().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Log.d("eventMode",myReader.GetEventMode().toString());
        //myReader.GetEventMode();
        //readerInfo = myReader.GetReaderInfo();
    } catch (CAENRFIDException e) {
        Log.d("error",e.toString());
    }
}
```